# Convolution Blur Filter doesn't work and brightens the image

Tags: java, image-processing

I've read about Convolution Filters recently and decided to try it out. I wanted to make code that blurs the image but what it ends up doing is brightening it. I've been looking at my code for some time now and can't find any mistakes. Could anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
final static int filterHeight =3;
final static int filterWidth = 3;
static double filter[][] = new double[][]{
    {1,1,1},
    {1,1,1},
    {1,1,1}     
    };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedImage img;
    BufferedImage result;
    try 
    {   File in = new File("in.jpg");
        File out = new File("out.jpg");
        img = ImageIO.read(in);          
        Color[][] pixels = new Color[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];           
        for(int i=0;i<img.getWidth();i++){
          for(int j=0;j<img.getHeight();j++){
              pixels[i][j]=new Color(img.getRGB(i,j),true);
          }
        }
        result = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType());
         for(int x=0;x<img.getWidth();x++){
             for(int y=0;y<img.getHeight();y++){                     
                 int r=0,g=0,b=0;                    
                 for(int i=0;i<filterWidth;i++){
                     for(int j=0;j<filterHeight;j++){
                         int imageX = (int)(x - filterWidth / 2 + i + img.getWidth()) % img.getWidth();
                          int imageY = (int)(y - filterHeight / 2 + j + img.getHeight()) % img.getHeight();
                          if(imageX<0 || imageY<0) System.out.println("ERROR: "+imageX+" "+imageY);
                          r+=pixels[imageX][imageY].getRed()*filter[i][j];                            
                          g+=pixels[imageX][imageY].getGreen()*filter[i][j];                              
                          b+=pixels[imageX][imageY].getBlue()*filter[i][j];                           
                     }

                     if(r>255) r=255;
                     if(r<0) r=0;
                     if(g>255) g=255;
                     if(g<0) g=0;
                     if(b>255) b=255;
                     if(b<0) b=0;   
                     Color color = new Color(img.getRGB(x,y),true)
                     Color colorBlur = new Color(r,g,b,color.getAlpha());
                     result.setRGB(x, y, colorBlur.getRGB());
                 }
             }
         } 


         ImageIO.write(result, "JPG", out );
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here is image before aplying filter:
[image: Before aplying filter]
And after:
[image: After aplying filter]

Comment: I believe you are missing a parameter for the division factor which should be the sum of the filter matrix, in your case, `9`. Otherwise you are doing a sum of `9` Pixels which would most likely mean `>255`.

Comment: @Elia you should add it as an answer ... also more usual is to divide (normalize) the matrix itself so the sum is 1 instead so you do not need to divide on each pixel ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options in order to get the result you desire.
Either you create a filter matrix with a sum of 1 (Like @Spektre mentioned in his comment above) or multiply the pixel's new value with a factor of `1 / sum(filterMatrix)`.

For a nice beginner tutorial of the concept of blurring I would recommend: 
[Concept of Blurring - www.TutorialsPoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/concept_of_blurring.htm)

Comment: so I added these 3 lines: `r=r/9;
      g=g/9;
      b=b/9;` and now image is not brightened but instead i don't see any differences, no blur

Comment: I made matrix bigger, 9x9 and now i can see some blur. So the bigger the matrix the stronger the blur? If so, why on every tutorial I find there are examples with 3x3 matrixes when the effect is not visible?

Comment: @matip From the link I added to my answer: "Because with greater mask, greater number of pixels are catered and one smooth transition is defined."

Comment: what you can do also if you enlarge the matrix is to adjust weights according to the distance. --> Gauss like filter